# return a list of accounts on the basis of search account name

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

how to return the list of account by the providing the account name in input text.
and after pressing the search button it should return the list of accounts with same name which is provided in input text.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="democlass">
   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:inputText value="{!searchBoxstring}" label="Search"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchbox}" > </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!result}" var="wl">
               <apex:column value="{!wl.name}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!wl.account.name}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!wl.id}"/>
            </apex:pageblockTable>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class democlass {
 public string searchboxstring {get;set;}
 public list < contact > result {get;set;}
 public democlass() {
  result = new list < Contact > ();
 }
 public void searchbox() {
  result = new List < Contact > ();
  result = [select ID, Name, account.name from Contact where Name = : searchboxstring];
 }
}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: vf pafe--
<apex:page controller="democlass">  
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >

 <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
 <apex:inputText value="{!searchBoxstring}" label="Search"/>
   <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchbox}" >

  </apex:commandButton>

    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!result}" var="wl">
     <apex:column value="{!wl.name}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!wl.account.name}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!wl.id}"/>
    </apex:pageblockTable>   
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: controller--
public class democlass {
 public string searchboxstring{get; set;}
 public list<contact> result {get; set;}

 public democlass()
 {
  result = new list<Contact>();
 }
 public void searchbox(){
  result=new List<Contact>();
  result=[select ID,Name, account.name from Contact where Name =:searchboxstring];
 }
}

Comment: lee, what is your issue?

Comment: it is fetching the results

Answer (score 2):

Your question says that you are looking for accounts with same name as User enter in search input but your SOQL is based on `Contact` object and Not `Account` object. In Case you want to search Accounts here are corrections:

```
<apex:page controller="democlass">
   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:inputText value="{!searchBoxstring}" label="Search"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchbox}" > </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!result}" var="wl">
               <apex:column value="{!wl.name}"/>              
               <apex:column value="{!wl.id}"/>
            </apex:pageblockTable>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and on class side

```
public class democlass {
 public string searchboxstring {get;set;}
 public list < Account> result {get;set;}
 public democlass() {
  result = new list < Account> ();
 }
 public void searchbox() {
  result = new List < Account> ();
  result = [select ID, Name from Account where Name = : searchboxstring];
 }
}
```

Note that I have removed `account.name` field as this field is not applicable if we have query on Account

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check for Account names, update your filter to meet that requirement as in below.

```
result = [select ID, Name, account.name from Contact where Account.Name = : searchboxstring];
```

So your commandbutton action method would be

```
public void searchbox() {
  result = new List < Contact > ();
  result = [select ID, Name, account.name from Contact where Account.Name = : searchboxstring];
 }
```